# laravel redis creating a set with ttl?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis, predis

so for creating a set I can do

```
Redis::sadd('example',[1,4,6,1,])
```

I tried many variations to also create a set with a ttl non worked:

```
Redis::sadd('example',100,[1,4,6,1,])
Redis::sadd('example',[1,4,6,1,],100)
Redis::saddex('example',100,[1,4,6,1,])
Redis::saddex('example',[1,4,6,1,],100)
```

Comment: Have you tried using expire after sadd?

Comment: @ChrisTanner yap its working thanks, no builtin function?

Comment: nope, whats the use case for wanting to expire the entire set? another data type might suit better.

Comment: @ChrisTanner i am using sets to store cache tags, each cache has a ttl so I don't want a case when a cache was flushed but the setes remain and when a new cache will be stored the old tags will remain, the cache must be a simple redis string so I am sync their ttl time to ensure consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For additional reference, If you want to check whether a [sorted set] key (in your case, the 'example') exists or not, You can either do the ff:

Proposal 1: (What you've preferred)

```
$iTtlRedisKey = Redis::ttl('example');
if ($iTtlRedisKey <= 0) {
    Redis::sadd('example', [1,4,6,1]);
    Redis::expire('example', 30);
}

$aSortedExampleSets = Redis::smembers('example');
// array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "6" }
```

Proposal 2: Using [exists] method

```
$bCheckRedisKey = Redis::exists('example');
if (boolval($bCheckRedisKey) !== true) {
    Redis::sadd('example', [1,4,6,1]);
    Redis::expire('example', 30);
}

$aSortedExampleSets = Redis::smembers('example');
// same results as well.
```

Comment: Thanks its not exactly what I was asking but Its indeed show how to use the expire method :)